# An optimum way to locate the right OFFSET for a given data

Tags: sqlite

To avoid fetching all data at once, which will cause out of memory, we are implementing paging in our app, by using `limit` & `offset`.

Each time, our app will only display 1 page.

```
Page 0 : select * from note order by order_id limit 10000 offset 0;
Page 1 : select * from note order by order_id limit 10000 offset 10000;
Page 2 : select * from note order by order_id limit 10000 offset 20000;
Page 3 : select * from note order by order_id limit 10000 offset 30000;
...
```

Whenever user adds a new data, we know the search criteria to locate data from SQLite.

```
select * from note where uuid = '1234-5678-9ABC';
```

However, we need to reload our app with the correct page.

But, we have no idea, how to have a good speed performance, to find out which page (which `offset`), the new data belongs to.

We can have the following brute force way to find out which offset the data belongs to

```
select * from (select * from note order by order_id limit 10000 offset 0) where uuid = '1234-5678-9ABC';

select * from (select * from note order by order_id limit 10000 offset 10000) where uuid = '1234-5678-9ABC';

select * from (select * from note order by order_id limit 10000 offset 20000) where uuid = '1234-5678-9ABC';

select * from (select * from note order by order_id limit 10000 offset 30000) where uuid = '1234-5678-9ABC';

...
```

But, that is highly inefficient.

Is there any "smart" way, so that we can have a good speed performance, to locate the right offset for a given data?

Thanks.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Comment: I am curious what and how you can access in RDBMS with O(1). Indexed access in RDBMS is O(log(N)). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you updating every user's page whenever any one user add data or are you just updating the page of the user who added data?

Comment: I want to ask a question. I can understand that when a user inserts new data you can filter them based on the uuid he provided when he inserted the data. But when he enters new data do you want to show only the new data in pages? In the last code example you provide I think you need to provide us with more information about the `order_id` field of the new inserted data, otherwise I don't see any guarantee that a page will be filled. It may be empty since it totally depends on the `order_id` of the new inserted data.

Comment: @JAAAY I want to show multiple data which includes the newly inserted data. Since, it is not possible to show the entire DB data, we can only show 1 page with LIMIT 10000. Hence, we need to know *which* page we should show. `order_id` is simply a numerical value in range 1, 2, 3...

Comment: @CheokYanCheng what happens if the user isn't on the page that includes the newly inserted data?

Answer (score 2):

## Use row_number() to find offset

The offset can be calculated by using the `row_number` window function to compute a row index. https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#builtins

##### FIND ROW INDEX

```
select
    uuid, (row_number() over (order by order_id) - 1) as row_index
from note
```

##### FIND OFFSET

The offset can be computed using modular arithmetic.

```
select row_index - (row_index % 10000) as offset
from note_row_index
where uuid = '1234-5678-9ABC'
```

##### USE OFFSET IN QUERY

```
with note_row_index(uuid, row_index) AS (
    select
        uuid, (row_number() over (order by order_id) - 1) as row_index
    from note
),
note_offset(offset) AS (
    select row_index - (row_index % 10000) as offset
    from note_row_index
    where uuid = '1234-5678-9ABC'
)
select *
from note
order by order_id
limit 10000
offset (select offset from note_offset)
```